# collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status Makefile:107: recipe for target ‘binary’ failed make: *** [binary] Error 1

Tags: compile, runtime-error, id

I am trying to compile ChatScript V7.55 on Ubuntu 16.04 but I got this error message:

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:107: recipe for target ‘binary’ failed
make: *** [binary] Error 1
```

What is this and how can I fix?

This is the whole result after tried this command: `make server`

```
************ LINUX VERSION ************
g++ constructCode.o duktape/duktape.c evserver.o csocket.o cs_ev.c dictionarySystem.o englishTagger.o factSystem.o json.o functionExecute.o english.o infer.o javascript.o jsmn.o markSystem.o mongodb.o os.o outputSystem.o patternSystem.o postgres.o privatesrc.o scriptCompile.o spellcheck.o secure.o systemVariables.o tagger.o testing.o textUtilities.o tokenSystem.o topicSystem.o userCache.o userSystem.o variableSystem.o mainSystem.o -L/usr/lib64 -lrt -lcurl  --verbose -pthread -DLOCKUSERFILE=1  -DEVSERVER=1 -DEVSERVER_FORK=1  -DDISCARDPOSTGRES=1 -DDISCARDMONGO=1 -DDISCARDMYSQL=1  -Ievserver -o ../BINARIES/ChatScript
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-L/usr/lib64' '-v' '-pthread' '-D' 'LOCKUSERFILE=1' '-D' 'EVSERVER=1' '-D' 'EVSERVER_FORK=1' '-D' 'DISCARDPOSTGRES=1' '-D' 'DISCARDMONGO=1' '-D' 'DISCARDMYSQL=1' '-I' 'evserver' '-o' '../BINARIES/ChatScript' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/cc1plus -quiet -v -I evserver -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -D LOCKUSERFILE=1 -D EVSERVER=1 -D EVSERVER_FORK=1 -D DISCARDPOSTGRES=1 -D DISCARDMONGO=1 -D DISCARDMYSQL=1 duktape/duktape.c -quiet -dumpbase duktape.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase duktape -version -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -o /tmp/ccz9862e.s
GNU C++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) version 5.4.0 20160609 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 5.4.0 20160609, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 evserver
 /usr/include/c++/5
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5
 /usr/include/c++/5/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) version 5.4.0 20160609 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 5.4.0 20160609, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: c3fdb80f2154421ceaf9e22c85325a8d
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-L/usr/lib64' '-v' '-pthread' '-D' 'LOCKUSERFILE=1' '-D' 'EVSERVER=1' '-D' 'EVSERVER_FORK=1' '-D' 'DISCARDPOSTGRES=1' '-D' 'DISCARDMONGO=1' '-D' 'DISCARDMYSQL=1' '-I' 'evserver' '-o' '../BINARIES/ChatScript' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v -I evserver --64 -o /tmp/ccm8SVai.o /tmp/ccz9862e.s
GNU assembler version 2.26.1 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.26.1
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-L/usr/lib64' '-v' '-pthread' '-D' 'LOCKUSERFILE=1' '-D' 'EVSERVER=1' '-D' 'EVSERVER_FORK=1' '-D' 'DISCARDPOSTGRES=1' '-D' 'DISCARDMONGO=1' '-D' 'DISCARDMYSQL=1' '-I' 'evserver' '-o' '../BINARIES/ChatScript' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/cc1plus -quiet -v -I evserver -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -D LOCKUSERFILE=1 -D EVSERVER=1 -D EVSERVER_FORK=1 -D DISCARDPOSTGRES=1 -D DISCARDMONGO=1 -D DISCARDMYSQL=1 cs_ev.c -quiet -dumpbase cs_ev.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase cs_ev -version -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -o /tmp/ccz9862e.s
GNU C++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) version 5.4.0 20160609 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 5.4.0 20160609, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 evserver
 /usr/include/c++/5
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5
 /usr/include/c++/5/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) version 5.4.0 20160609 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 5.4.0 20160609, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: c3fdb80f2154421ceaf9e22c85325a8d
In file included from cs_ev.c:5:0:
evserver/ev.c:1254:31: warning: ‘ev_default_loop_ptr’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
   EV_API_DECL struct ev_loop *ev_default_loop_ptr = 0; /* needs to be initialised to make it a definition despite extern */
                               ^
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-L/usr/lib64' '-v' '-pthread' '-D' 'LOCKUSERFILE=1' '-D' 'EVSERVER=1' '-D' 'EVSERVER_FORK=1' '-D' 'DISCARDPOSTGRES=1' '-D' 'DISCARDMONGO=1' '-D' 'DISCARDMYSQL=1' '-I' 'evserver' '-o' '../BINARIES/ChatScript' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v -I evserver --64 -o /tmp/ccRZyE1l.o /tmp/ccz9862e.s
GNU assembler version 2.26.1 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.26.1
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-L/usr/lib64' '-v' '-pthread' '-D' 'LOCKUSERFILE=1' '-D' 'EVSERVER=1' '-D' 'EVSERVER_FORK=1' '-D' 'DISCARDPOSTGRES=1' '-D' 'DISCARDMONGO=1' '-D' 'DISCARDMYSQL=1' '-I' 'evserver' '-o' '../BINARIES/ChatScript' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccIwnEUp.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lpthread -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -z relro -o ../BINARIES/ChatScript /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../.. constructCode.o /tmp/ccm8SVai.o evserver.o csocket.o /tmp/ccRZyE1l.o dictionarySystem.o englishTagger.o factSystem.o json.o functionExecute.o english.o infer.o javascript.o jsmn.o markSystem.o mongodb.o os.o outputSystem.o patternSystem.o postgres.o privatesrc.o scriptCompile.o spellcheck.o secure.o systemVariables.o tagger.o testing.o textUtilities.o tokenSystem.o topicSystem.o userCache.o userSystem.o variableSystem.o mainSystem.o -lrt -lcurl -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lpthread -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
evserver.o: In function `evsrv_do_chat(Client_t*)':
evserver.cpp:(.text+0x161a): undefined reference to `LogChat(long, char*, char*, char*, int, char*, char*)'
mainSystem.o: In function `InitSystem(int, char**, char*, char*, char*, USERFILESYSTEM*, void (*)(char*), void (*)(char*))':
mainSystem.cpp:(.text+0x2687): undefined reference to `ReadTopicFiles(char*, unsigned int, int)'
mainSystem.cpp:(.text+0x273d): undefined reference to `ReadTopicFiles(char*, unsigned int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:107: recipe for target 'binary' failed
make: *** [binary] Error 1
```

This is the `make file` contents too: https://github.com/bwilcox-1234/ChatScript/blob/master/SRC/Makefile

I ran `./autogen.sh` inside the ../SRC/evserver and this is the results:

```
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in '.'.
libtoolize: linking file './ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: Consider adding 'AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([m4])' to configure.ac,
libtoolize: and rerunning libtoolize and aclocal.
libtoolize: Consider adding '-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
configure.ac:6: warning: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE: two- and three-arguments forms are deprecated.  For more info, see:
configure.ac:6: http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Modernize-AM_005fINIT_005fAUTOMAKE-invocation
configure.ac:10: installing './compile'
configure.ac:6: installing './missing'
Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
```

After that ran `./configure` inside ../SRC/evserver and this is the result:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
configure: WARNING: Libtool does not cope well with whitespace in `pwd`
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking sys/inotify.h usability... yes
checking sys/inotify.h presence... yes
checking for sys/inotify.h... yes
checking sys/epoll.h usability... yes
checking sys/epoll.h presence... yes
checking for sys/epoll.h... yes
checking sys/event.h usability... no
checking sys/event.h presence... no
checking for sys/event.h... no
checking port.h usability... no
checking port.h presence... no
checking for port.h... no
checking poll.h usability... yes
checking poll.h presence... yes
checking for poll.h... yes
checking sys/select.h usability... yes
checking sys/select.h presence... yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking sys/eventfd.h usability... yes
checking sys/eventfd.h presence... yes
checking for sys/eventfd.h... yes
checking sys/signalfd.h usability... yes
checking sys/signalfd.h presence... yes
checking for sys/signalfd.h... yes
checking for inotify_init... yes
checking for epoll_ctl... yes
checking for kqueue... no
checking for port_create... no
checking for poll... yes
checking for select... yes
checking for eventfd... yes
checking for signalfd... yes
checking for clock_gettime... yes
checking for nanosleep... yes
checking for library containing floor... -lm
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
```

This is `make server` result after them:

```
************ LINUX VERSION ************
g++ constructCode.o duktape/duktape.c evserver.o csocket.o cs_ev.c dictionarySystem.o englishTagger.o factSystem.o json.o functionExecute.o english.o infer.o javascript.o jsmn.o markSystem.o mongodb.o os.o outputSystem.o patternSystem.o postgres.o privatesrc.o scriptCompile.o spellcheck.o secure.o systemVariables.o tagger.o testing.o textUtilities.o tokenSystem.o topicSystem.o userCache.o userSystem.o variableSystem.o mainSystem.o -L/usr/lib64 -lrt -lcurl  --verbose -pthread -DLOCKUSERFILE=1  -DEVSERVER=1 -DEVSERVER_FORK=1  -DDISCARDPOSTGRES=1 -DDISCARDMONGO=1 -DDISCARDMYSQL=1  -Ievserver -o ../BINARIES/ChatScript
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-L/usr/lib64' '-v' '-pthread' '-D' 'LOCKUSERFILE=1' '-D' 'EVSERVER=1' '-D' 'EVSERVER_FORK=1' '-D' 'DISCARDPOSTGRES=1' '-D' 'DISCARDMONGO=1' '-D' 'DISCARDMYSQL=1' '-I' 'evserver' '-o' '../BINARIES/ChatScript' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/cc1plus -quiet -v -I evserver -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -D LOCKUSERFILE=1 -D EVSERVER=1 -D EVSERVER_FORK=1 -D DISCARDPOSTGRES=1 -D DISCARDMONGO=1 -D DISCARDMYSQL=1 duktape/duktape.c -quiet -dumpbase duktape.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase duktape -version -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -o /tmp/ccY9JQBg.s
GNU C++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) version 5.4.0 20160609 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 5.4.0 20160609, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 evserver
 /usr/include/c++/5
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5
 /usr/include/c++/5/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) version 5.4.0 20160609 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 5.4.0 20160609, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: c3fdb80f2154421ceaf9e22c85325a8d
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-L/usr/lib64' '-v' '-pthread' '-D' 'LOCKUSERFILE=1' '-D' 'EVSERVER=1' '-D' 'EVSERVER_FORK=1' '-D' 'DISCARDPOSTGRES=1' '-D' 'DISCARDMONGO=1' '-D' 'DISCARDMYSQL=1' '-I' 'evserver' '-o' '../BINARIES/ChatScript' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v -I evserver --64 -o /tmp/ccBVYgwH.o /tmp/ccY9JQBg.s
GNU assembler version 2.26.1 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.26.1
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-L/usr/lib64' '-v' '-pthread' '-D' 'LOCKUSERFILE=1' '-D' 'EVSERVER=1' '-D' 'EVSERVER_FORK=1' '-D' 'DISCARDPOSTGRES=1' '-D' 'DISCARDMONGO=1' '-D' 'DISCARDMYSQL=1' '-I' 'evserver' '-o' '../BINARIES/ChatScript' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/cc1plus -quiet -v -I evserver -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -D LOCKUSERFILE=1 -D EVSERVER=1 -D EVSERVER_FORK=1 -D DISCARDPOSTGRES=1 -D DISCARDMONGO=1 -D DISCARDMYSQL=1 cs_ev.c -quiet -dumpbase cs_ev.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase cs_ev -version -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -o /tmp/ccY9JQBg.s
GNU C++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) version 5.4.0 20160609 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 5.4.0 20160609, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 evserver
 /usr/include/c++/5
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5
 /usr/include/c++/5/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) version 5.4.0 20160609 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 5.4.0 20160609, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: c3fdb80f2154421ceaf9e22c85325a8d
In file included from cs_ev.c:5:0:
evserver/ev.c:1254:31: warning: ‘ev_default_loop_ptr’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
   EV_API_DECL struct ev_loop *ev_default_loop_ptr = 0; /* needs to be initialis
                               ^
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-L/usr/lib64' '-v' '-pthread' '-D' 'LOCKUSERFILE=1' '-D' 'EVSERVER=1' '-D' 'EVSERVER_FORK=1' '-D' 'DISCARDPOSTGRES=1' '-D' 'DISCARDMONGO=1' '-D' 'DISCARDMYSQL=1' '-I' 'evserver' '-o' '../BINARIES/ChatScript' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v -I evserver --64 -o /tmp/ccWFo098.o /tmp/ccY9JQBg.s
GNU assembler version 2.26.1 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.26.1
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-L/usr/lib64' '-v' '-pthread' '-D' 'LOCKUSERFILE=1' '-D' 'EVSERVER=1' '-D' 'EVSERVER_FORK=1' '-D' 'DISCARDPOSTGRES=1' '-D' 'DISCARDMONGO=1' '-D' 'DISCARDMYSQL=1' '-I' 'evserver' '-o' '../BINARIES/ChatScript' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/cc9oL8PA.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lpthread -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -z relro -o ../BINARIES/ChatScript /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../.. constructCode.o /tmp/ccBVYgwH.o evserver.o csocket.o /tmp/ccWFo098.o dictionarySystem.o englishTagger.o factSystem.o json.o functionExecute.o english.o infer.o javascript.o jsmn.o markSystem.o mongodb.o os.o outputSystem.o patternSystem.o postgres.o privatesrc.o scriptCompile.o spellcheck.o secure.o systemVariables.o tagger.o testing.o textUtilities.o tokenSystem.o topicSystem.o userCache.o userSystem.o variableSystem.o mainSystem.o -lrt -lcurl -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lpthread -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:107: recipe for target 'binary' failed
make: *** [binary] Error 1
```

Comment: `ld` is a program that loads shared libraries. You are probably missing some. Did you run `configure` script before executing `make`? A properly written `configure` should catch missing libraries errors.

Comment: There is a file named `configure` in `evserver` folder but when I try to execute it by ` ./configure ' it says `sudo: ./configure: command not found
`

Comment: You don't need to be sudo to build code, well, normally, if the build is written properly. Does `configure` file look like a shell script? If so, maybe the way you obtained your sources, the file mode bits were lost (eg. you downloaded a zip archive). If this is the case, `chmod +x ./configure` and run it.

Comment: @wvxvw: this is the content of configure file: https://github.com/bwilcox-1234/ChatScript/blob/master/SRC/evserver/configure

Comment: Yup, it's a typical `configure` file generated by autotools. You need to set execution bits for this file and run it, then look at the output to see if all dependencies are present.

Comment: @wvxvw: unfortunately I am newbie in Linux and don't know what are those bits amd how can I set them!

Comment: Oh, it's just another way of saying run `chmod +x ./configure`. The bits I'm talking about are the bits in the value known as "mask" or "file mode mask", often written as base-8 number, for example 0777 would mean - owner can read/write/execute, owner's group can read/write/execute, anyone can read/write/execute. `chmod` program (which should've been named "change mode") modifies this value, in particular, given `+x` it would make the given file executable by all three entities.

Comment: @wvxvw: I did it first time you said but when I try to run `./configure` it says: `bash: ./configure: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: It's strange and I don't know why I get this error! the file exist but Linux says not exist!

Comment: `^M` would imply that there is a carriage return where `bash` expects line break. Did you by any chance open the file and saved it using some "smart" text editor (eg. Eclipse), which might have "corrected" line endings to be "windows-style"? The easiest way, probably, would be to re-download the `configure` file, else you could try what this answer suggests: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3891101/5691066

Comment: I used dos2unix and it says: `nfigure
dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x07 found at line 11836
dos2unix: Skipping binary file configure` I looked to that line and found this:  `FS = ""` . in github it seems its nothing between " " but when I copy it it shows some strange character between " " .

Comment: Well, that's a bell character (once used to play sound using simple sound device on the computer's motherboard...) Then just use `sed` instead? Like in the following answer from the question I linked above? Or you could delete that character temporarily and put it back in later.

Comment: @wvxvw: I removed it and tryied `./autogen.sh` and `/configure` but I have error after `make server` command. I have edited my question with results of them.

Comment: You are not supposed to run `autogen.sh`, unless you are a developer who works on this project. It requires dependencies that you, as a user, may not know where to get / are not expected to be able to install. If your copy of the project already had `configure` script - it was already prepared for users, not for developers. As to your error - my guess is that you are supposed to build something else before building the server. Try first `make clean`, then `make` then `make server`.

Comment: Also, the configure output indicates that you are missing some headers / libraries. I'm not sure if those are crucial to you, but `port.h`, `event.h` and `kqueue` are missing. Perhaps try installing the dependencies? `apt-file -x search '.*/event.h$'` give a bunch of results, but my guess that the one the developers had in mind comes from `libevent-dev` package. `port.h` - could be Linux headers. I couldn't find any readme in their GitHub repository, you would need to ask the developers to assist you with these.

Comment: Is't the problem with this line: `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main' `

Comment: Well, sort of, right, but `_start` isn't a kind of function a programmer would write. It is generated by assembler from a template. This is a function that the runtime calls in order to start executing the program. `_start` will later transfer control to your `main` function. However, the linker isn't able to find an archive where you must've compiled your code containing `main` function - this is why it gives this error.

Comment: Also, looking more closely, it seems like this recipe was intended for compiling a shared library, so it shouldn't have a `main` function. You should really ask the developers of the project about its compilation. It doesn't seem to be thoroughly tested or explained for general use.